# how to add spaces at the begining using ansible playbook

Tags: ansible

I have written a ansible playbook to add 2 variables at the end of the file. There is a file  /home/ec2-user/etc_hosts/tasks/main.yml which has IP address and hostname as https://github.com/shettypriy/ansible/blob/master/ansible

I am trying to insert a new IP address and the corresponding hostname. Playbook I wrote adds the hostname and IP address but there is no indentation as shown here https://github.com/shettypriy/ansible/blob/master/no_indentation

How to maintain the indentation after adding new IP address and hostname

```
- name: updating etc_hosts/tasks/main.yml
  blockinfile:
     path: /home/ec2-user/etc_hosts/tasks/main.yml
     insertafter: "^with_items"
     marker: ""
     block: |
        "{{ new_server_ip }} {{ server_name }}"
     backup: yes
```

Answer (score 0):

A number after the pipe | tells Jinja2 where the next indentation starts. The code in the question is indented by 3 spaces. Let's use it. This means the first column of the block (under the letter 'c') starts 3 spaces to the right from the previous indentation level (under the letter 'b').

```
block: |3
   This line starts at 1st column
```

Let's shift it 4 more spaces to the right to align the new line *with_items:*

```
block: |3
       - "{{ new_server_ip }} {{ server_name }}"
```

Without explicit indentation `|<number>` the default configuration of the *block* is to strip all whitespaces.

**Example 1.**

The regex doesn't work because *with_items* doesn't start at 1st column

```
insertafter: "^with_items"
```

Correct code

```
   insertafter: "^\\s*with_items:(.*)$"
   block: |3
           - "ww4.xx4.yy4.zz4 hostname4"
```

give

```
- name: add server name and ip address in /etc/hosts file
  lineinfile: dest=/etc/hosts line="{{ item }}"
  with_items:
# BEGIN ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK
     - "ww4.xx4.yy4.zz4 hostname4"
# END ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK
     - "ww1.xx1.yy1.zz1 hostname1"
     - "ww2.xx2.yy2.zz2 hostname2"
     - "ww3.xx3.yy3.zz3 hostname3"
```

**Example 2.**

The code below

```
   insertafter: EOF
   block: |3
           - "ww4.xx4.yy4.zz4 hostname4"
```

give

```
- name: add server name and ip address in /etc/hosts file
  lineinfile: dest=/etc/hosts line="{{ item }}"
  with_items:
     - "ww1.xx1.yy1.zz1 hostname1"
     - "ww2.xx2.yy2.zz2 hostname2"
     - "ww3.xx3.yy3.zz3 hostname3"
# BEGIN ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK
     - "ww4.xx4.yy4.zz4 hostname4"
# END ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK
```

**Note.** Without the marker `marker: ""` the module is not idempotent.

Comment: I am trying the following code now, but this is adding at the top. Instaed I want to add it at the end of the file. I also used insertafter: EOF still it gets added on the top

Comment: - name: updating the known host key
  blockinfile:
     path: /home/ec2-user/sdf_known_hosts/tasks/main.yml
     marker: ""
     block: |3
            - "{{ new_server_ip }} {{ server_name }} {{ server_key }}
     backup: yes
- name: Remove blank lines blockinfile put in
  lineinfile:
     path: /home/ec2-user/sdf_known_hosts/tasks/main.yml
     state: absent
     regexp: '^$'

Comment: The code in the comments is hard to read. Put it into the question and make it [minimal](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I have uploaded the code in the github URL https://github.com/shettypriy/ansible/blob/master/ansible2 .The code that I uploaded is adding at the top. I want it to be added at the end of the file. I also used insertafter: EOF still it gets added on the top

Comment: The functionality of blockinfile is limited. [template](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/template_module.html#template-template-a-file-out-to-a-remote-server) is a stable and robust option.